# what " do watering holes" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Bowness [name of pub] does all right for watering holes, but just then they were too busy.

What does that mean?

source: "New Beginnings" by "limeyLady"

Comment: Can you check that quote, it looks incorrect. Or can you link to the source? I found "New Beginnings" by "LimeyLady", but I couldn't find that line.

Comment: Bowness does all right for watering holes, but just then they were too busy.

Comment: Please [edit] to put the correct quote exactly as it appears in the book. Add more context if possible

Answer (score 1):

"[Bowness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowness-on-Windermere)" is not the name of a pub, it is the name of a town in Northern England. It is popular with tourists.

A "watering hole" is a casual way of saying "pub", or "place you can get a drink".

To say "*A town* does all right for watering holes" means that it has plenty of pubs.

So your sentence if quoted correctly would mean "There are plenty of pubs in Bowness, but at that time they were all too busy".